# Unable to run gitlab-ctl reconfigure after updating from 10.6.4 to 10.8.7 on RHEL 6

Tags: gitlab, upstart, rhel6

I am working on the upgrade to the latest 11.x version of gitlab but needed to upgrade to 10.8.7 first from 10.6.4 on RHEL 6. That upgrade proceeded normally, then I attempted the upgrade to latest 11.x but it failed with a message about deprecating mattermost configurations in gitlab.rb. I removed all mattermost config from gitlab.rb and then attempted to run 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure' and it failed. I restored the original gitlab.rb and reran reconfigure and it still failed.

So currently I am stuck at 10.8.7 and unable to run reconfigure. Any help on understanding how to fix the errors shown in the output below would be appreciated (here is the error: "execute[initctl reload-configuration] (runit::upstart line 29) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - initctl").

I also tried upgrading upstart to the next minor version but no change.

```
Starting Chef Client, version 13.6.4
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["gitlab"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - package (0.1.0)
  - gitlab (0.0.1)
  - postgresql (0.1.0)
  - registry (0.1.0)
  - mattermost (0.1.0)
  - consul (0.0.0)
  - gitaly (0.1.0)
  - letsencrypt (0.1.0)
  - nginx (0.1.0)
  - runit (0.14.2)
  - acme (3.1.0)
  - crond (0.1.0)
  - compat_resource (12.19.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  Converging 497 resources
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * directory[Create /var/opt/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/gitconfig] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::web-server
  * account[Webserver user and group] action create
    * group[Webserver user and group] action create (up to date)
    * linux_user[Webserver user and group] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::users
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * account[GitLab user and group] action create
    * group[GitLab user and group] action create (up to date)
    * linux_user[GitLab user and group] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-shell
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell] action create (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a config.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/.gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
  * execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions] action run
    - execute /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions
  * bash[Set proper security context on ssh files for selinux] action run (skipped due to only_if)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/builds] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/builds] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/cache] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/cache] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/tmp] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/tmp] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/working] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/tmp] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/backups] action create
    * ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/backups] action run (skipped due to not_if)
     (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci] action create (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab-registry.key] action create (skipped due to only_if)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.secret] action delete (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secret] action delete (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a database.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/database.yml] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/database.yml to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/database.yml] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a secrets.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secrets.yml] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/secrets.yml to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secrets.yml] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a resque.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/resque.yml] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/resque.yml to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/resque.yml] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a redis.cache.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * templatesymlink[Create a redis.queues.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * templatesymlink[Create a redis.shared_state.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * templatesymlink[Create a aws.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action delete
    * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/aws.yml] action delete (up to date)
    * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/aws.yml] action delete (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a smtp_settings.rb and create a symlink to Rails root] action delete
    * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/smtp_settings.rb] action delete (up to date)
    * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb] action delete (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a gitlab.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a rack_attack.rb and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/rack_attack.rb] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/rack_attack.rb] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a gitlab_workhorse_secret and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab_workhorse_secret] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_workhorse_secret to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab_workhorse_secret] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * templatesymlink[Create a gitlab_shell_secret and create a symlink to Rails root] action create
    * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
    * link[Link /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_shell_secret to /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/relative_url.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/relative_url.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * env_dir[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env] action create
    * directory[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/HOME] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/RAILS_ENV] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/LD_PRELOAD] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/SIDEKIQ_MEMORY_KILLER_MAX_RSS] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/BUNDLE_GEMFILE] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/PATH] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/ICU_DATA] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/PYTHONPATH] action create (up to date)
    * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/EXECJS_RUNTIME] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/tmp] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/uploads] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log] action create (up to date)
  * link[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq.log] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/schema.rb] action create (up to date)
  * remote_file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/VERSION] action create (up to date)
  * remote_file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/REVISION] action create (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/RUBY_VERSION] action create (up to date)
  * execute[chown -R root:root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public] action run
    - execute chown -R root:root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/config.ru] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::add_trusted_certs
  * directory[/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/README] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[Move existing certs and link to /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs] action run (skipped due to only_if)
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * service[create a temporary unicorn service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * service[create a temporary sidekiq service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * service[create a temporary mailroom service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: runit::upstart
  * cookbook_file[/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf] action create (up to date)
  * execute[initctl reload-configuration] action run

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[initctl reload-configuration]'
    ================================================================================

    Errno::ENOENT
    -------------
    No such file or directory - initctl

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/runit/recipes/upstart.rb

     29: execute "initctl reload-configuration" do
     30:   command "initctl reload-configuration"
     31: end
     32:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/runit/recipes/upstart.rb:29:in `from_file'

    execute("initctl reload-configuration") do
      action [:run]
      default_guard_interpreter :execute
      command "initctl reload-configuration"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      user nil
      declared_type :execute
      cookbook_name "runit"
      recipe_name "upstart"
      domain nil
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.6.4
    platform=redhat
    platform_version=6.9
    ruby=ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

execute[initctl reload-configuration] (runit::upstart line 29) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - initctl

Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated in 08 seconds

Deprecations:

* Mattermost
        Detected deprecated Mattermost settings. Starting with GitLab 11.0, these settings are no longer supported.
        Check http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/gitlab-mattermost/#upgrading-gitlab-mattermost-from-versions-prior-to-11-0 for details.

        * mattermost['db2_backup_created']
        * mattermost['db2_team_name']
        * mattermost['service_enable_incoming_webhooks']
        * mattermost['service_enable_post_username_override']
        * mattermost['service_enable_post_icon_override']
        * mattermost['service_enable_outgoing_webhooks']
        * mattermost['service_enable_commands']
        * mattermost['team_max_users_per_team']
        * mattermost['team_enable_team_listing']
        * mattermost['service_enable_custom_emoji']
        * mattermost['email_enable_sign_in_with_email']
        * mattermost['email_enable_sign_up_with_email']
        * mattermost['email_send_email_notifications']
        * mattermost['email_require_email_verification']
        * mattermost['email_smtp_username']
        * mattermost['email_smtp_password']
        * mattermost['email_smtp_server']
        * mattermost['email_smtp_port']
        * mattermost['email_connection_security']
        * mattermost['email_feedback_name']
        * mattermost['email_feedback_email']
        * mattermost['support_email']
        * mattermost['privacy_show_email_address']
        * mattermost['privacy_show_full_name']
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause was that initctl was not in the path gitlab was expecting. I created a link and then it worked

```
sudo ln -s /sbin/initctl /usr/bin/initctl
```